# PINBLOCK does not contain a valid value

Tags: hsm, iso8583

While trying to run a transaction, I am always getting this error as a response while using the right TPK to encrypt my PINBLOCK which has been confirmed already.
Although, what i am not quite sure of is the algorithm that's been used for the encryption of this data which as a result is throwing this error because, the algorithm been expected is a DES algorithm (from the documentation given) which was giving the **translatedPINBlock: 99-Wrong Format**, but after updating my code to making use of

```
public String do3DESEncryption(String key, String text) {
        String encryptedInfo = null;
        try {
            String key1 = key.substring(0, 16);
            String key2 = key.substring(16);
            encryptedInfo = doDESEncryption(key1, text);
            encryptedInfo = doDESDecryption(key2, encryptedInfo);
            encryptedInfo = doDESEncryption(key1, encryptedInfo);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("do3DESEncryption error message"+ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return encryptedInfo;
    }
```

The algorithm i was making use of before is stated below

```
public String doDESEncryption(String key, String text) {
        String encryptedInfo = "";
        try {
            byte[] theCph = null;
            byte[] theKey = null;
            byte[] theMsg = null;
            theKey = hexToBytes(key);
            theMsg = hexToBytes(text);
            DESKeySpec ks = new DESKeySpec(theKey);
            SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey ky = kf.generateSecret(ks);
            Cipher cf = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
            cf.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ky);
            theCph = cf.doFinal(theMsg);
            encryptedInfo = bytesToHex(theCph);
            System.out.println("Just the ePINBLOCK"+encryptedInfo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedInfo;
    }
```

I will like to know, if i am actually doing my encryption well cos, i have access to the client side only. I just want to be sure of the thing i am doing at my own end and to know, if there is any other correction i can make to avoid getting this error. **translatedPINBlock: 99-Wrong Format**

this is the error log from machine one

> Postilion exception: [postilion.realtime.sdk.crypto.XPinLengthError]
>   Description: A cryptographic operation () involving key
>   'SBP_KVP' failed, because invalid data was supplied. The invalid data
>   was in field 'PIN'. The data was invalid because PIN length is
>   invalid. ID: [126] Data: [none]
>
> at
>   postilion.realtime.sdk.crypto.impl.rg7000.ARG7000KeyImpl.processErrorCode(ARG7000KeyImpl.java:170)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.sdk.crypto.impl.rg7000.RG7000DesKeyImpl.processErrorCode(RG7000DesKeyImpl.java:1320)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.sdk.crypto.impl.rg7000.RG7000DesKeyImpl.processResponseAndErrorCode(RG7000DesKeyImpl.java:1378)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.sdk.crypto.impl.rg7000.RG7000DesKvpIbmImpl.verifyPin(RG7000DesKvpIbmImpl.java:365)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.sdk.crypto.DesKvpIbm.verifyPin(DesKvpIbm.java:613) 
>   at
>   postilion.postcard.authorizers.IBMPinVerificationData.verify(IBMPinVerificationData.java:281)
>   at
>   postilion.postcard.authorizers.validators.ValidatorPinPostCard.validatePin(ValidatorPinPostCard.java:550)
>   at
>   postilion.postcard.authorizers.validators.ValidatorPinPostCard.validatePinAndPopulateMessageReasonCode(ValidatorPinPostCard.java:281)
>   at
>   postilion.postcard.authorizers.validators.ValidatorPinPostCard.validateOnline(ValidatorPinPostCard.java:78)
>   at
>   postilion.postcard.authorizers.pipeline.adapter.IssuerValidatorAdapter.process(IssuerValidatorAdapter.java:117)
>   at
>   postilion.postcard.authorizers.pipeline.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:315)
>   at
>   postilion.postcard.authorizers.AuthorizerPostCard.authorizeRequestOnline(AuthorizerPostCard.java:339)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.apps.tranmgr.EventHandlerReqReqMessage.attemptLocalAuthorization(EventHandlerReqReqMessage.java:145)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.apps.tranmgr.EventHandlerTranReq.processTran(EventHandlerTranReq.java:88)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.apps.tranmgr.EventHandlerMessage.process(EventHandlerMessage.java:64)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.apps.tranmgr.EventHandlerMessage.processMsg(EventHandlerMessage.java:40)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.apps.tranmgr.TransactionManager.processNodeMessage(TransactionManager.java:1435)
>   at
>   postilion.realtime.apps.tranmgr.TransactionManager.processEvent(TransactionManager.java:1360)
>   at postilion.realtime.sdk.util.Processor.run(Processor.java:213)  at
>   postilion.realtime.sdk.env.AppProcessor.run(AppProcessor.java:136)
>   [Error event 126]

Error log from machine 2

> :: process0200
>   messageRetrievedFromStore[51]: 22314F270B978B54 INFO   | jvm 1    |
>   2017/01/04 16:00:21 | Jan 04, 2017 4:00:21 PM
>   hsmm.ncs.core.MessageProcessor processPINBlock INFO   | jvm 1    |
>   2017/01/04 16:00:21 | INFO: MessageProcessor :: process0200 ::
>
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > translatedPINBlock: 99-Wrong Format INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/04 16:00:21 | Jan 04, 2017 4:00:21 PM
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >                                                 hsmm.ncs.core.MessageProcessor process0200

Comment: You must use certain formats to encrypt PIN value. http://www.paymentsystemsblog.com/2010/03/03/pin-block-formats/

Comment: thanks for the comment, i do appreciate...the PINBLOCK is actually been generated from the device using the ISO-0 format which is also same format been expected by the HSM, so..my doubt is on the algorithm i am making use of. I do sincerely appreciate your time too

Comment: How long is the key, isn't it triple des? Because by my experience 3DES is preferred now for most of solutions

Comment: i was making use of just DES before, but now making use of 3DES..and the length of the key is 32

Comment: 3DES does not have a 32-byte key. 3DES keys are 168-bits in in 24-bytes (the lsb of each byte is unused). Most likely extra bytes will be ignored but this indicates some misunderstanding of the key. Sometimes a double DES key is used with the first 8-bytes repeated for bytes 16-23, some 3DES implementations will do this automatically but not all. You really need to determine the keyL DES vs 3DES and if 3DES 2 or 3 byte key and how to handle the key. Decryption data with the wrong key will produce incorrect data so any error message based on an incorrect key is not meaningful.

Comment: Thanks so much @zaph, I will sincerely do appreciate a sample from you pls.

Comment: Are you sure you are using right key. If you want to encrypt PIN on your application you have to use clear TPK. Maybe they give you TP_Under_LMK , if this is the case you must get clear TPK.

Comment: I am actually making use of the encrypted TPK gotten from my PIN key message request...then, I will have to decrypt it using the plain TMK to get my clear TPK BEING USED FOR TRANSACTIONS

Answer (score 1):

Current practice requires the encryption to be 3DES, possibly with a double length key.

Comment: thanks so much @zaph , i have upated the question and i got the error log above (given to me by the person helping to monitor transactions from my end), i sincerely do appreciate your time pls.